# HTML vs. XML - difference

Tags: html, xml

What's the difference between HTML and XML?

I'm well familiar with HTML, but my knowlege about XML very limited.

In old-fashioned HTML we were forced to write something like:

```
<div>
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

In other words, in HTML we have limited set of tags.

Unlike XML, where we can specify our own tags:

```
<letter>
  <to>John</to>
  <from>Mike</from>
  <date>01.01.2017<date>
  <contents>Hi!</contents>
</letter>
```

However, now I have Chrome installed on my computer, and it's history page looks like this:

```
<body>
  <history-app>
    <history-router>...</history-router>
    <history-toolbar>...</history-toolbar>
    <div>
      <history-side-bar>...</history-side-bar>
      <iron-pages>...</iron-pages>
    </div>
  </history-app>
</body>
```

As you can see, there are a lot of tags, which are not exist in HTML.

The same case with AngularJS, where we can create our own custom tags.

So I'm a bit confused is there any real difference between XML and HTML in modern times.

Also, maybe (I'm not sure, because as I said, my knowledge about XML is very limited), XML provides some rules (schemes) about how tags **can** and **can not** be organized. For example, I have some scheme called "Standard Letter", and according to this scheme, tag `<letter>` should **always** contain tags `<to>` and `<from>`, and moreover, `<to>` must be the first. Hm... but HTML also has such requirements. For example, `<table>` always must have `<tr>` inside, and `<td>` inside `<tr>`.

Previously, I've asked about [difference between DocBook and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639079/docbook-vs-html-difference). But I've also decided to reformulate it in a new manner, as described above (XML vs. HTML).

Comment: http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1204/XML/htmlVxml.html

Comment: Although there is certainly some relation (there was XHTML, a version of HTML that was XML as well) the question per-se doesn't really make more sense than asking what's the difference between Paris and London. I have the impression that you're more interested in something specific: whether you can create your own HTML tags.

Comment: This is far too broad of a question, and just a little bit of research can find the answer. Both are descended from SGML, a more generic markup language, so both use tags, attributes, etc.. Beyond that, there are many, many differences.

Comment: @Pete, Thanks. I'm still doesn't understand the difference, but this article confirmed some of my own guesses (about the role of a sheme).

Answer (score 4):

HTML and XML are both markup languages that share a common heritage with an older markup language, SGML.

- **Use HTML** (and CSS) when you wish to target presentation in web
  browser.
- **Use XML** when you wish to define custom markup for documents.  XML
  will allow a document to be marked up for *what content is* rather than
  for *how content should look*.  Content can then be decoupled from its
  presentation, allowing content to be independently translated to different
  media such as web or print automatically.

(And use JSON when you wish to define custom data formats that are [data rather than document oriented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045237/json-or-xml-which-is-better).)

Comment: Ok, but *why* it's better to use XML for documents? What's the practical advantage?

Comment: Answer updated to explain that XML provides for markup according to *what content is* rather than *how content should look*.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer and I'm thankful for it, but separating content from presentation is a feature which is exist in *both* XML and HTML. It's not exclusive XML feature.

Comment: I did say to *use XML when you wish to define custom markup for documents*.  I'm happy to educate, but if you're looking for an academic argument or extended discussion, this site isn't the proper venue.